# How to validate the input field based on conditions in angular 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, regex

I have a input field which should validate text entered based on the logic condition.
condition which it should validate are : -

1.There should not be any space in the formula.

2.The operators(and,or) should be lowercase and enclosed in {}.

3.Number of opening ( and closing ) will be equal.

4.All the entered task_id should present in the taskList Array.

5. No duplicate task_id should not accept.

Example:- (task_1{and}task_2){or}task_3

```js
let taskList = ['task_1', 'task_2', 'task_3', 'task_4', 'task_5'];
let myModel = '';

onBlurMethod(){


}
```

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myModel" (blur)="onBlurMethod()">
```

I have a array which contains tasks_id, and it should throw error if the condition is not satisfied.
I trying to use using regex.

Comment: Your snippet has an error

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular forms **https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview**

**.component.html**

> ```
>     <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onBlurMethod()">
>     <nav for="userName" class="textinput">
>         <input type="text" formControlName="myModel" class="form-control" />
>     </nav>
>     </form
> ```

**.component.ts**

```
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private locationService:LocationService,

    private formBuilder:FormBuilder
    ) { 
      this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        myModel: ['', Validators.required,Validators.pattern("")],
      });
    }
  onBlurMethod(){
    console.log(this.loginForm.value.myModel);
  }
```

In  **Validators.pattern("")** you can write the pattern

Since, I didn't understood your logic of validation but if have any doubt feel free to ask your doubt. Later I can add more details if you add more info to your query
thank you